# Flutter downloaded executables cannot execute on host even after installing lib32-gcc-libs on Archcraft

Tags: flutter, archlinux

I am running Flutter on Archcraft and I am getting the following error message:

```
❯ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on Archcraft 6.2.10-arch1-1, locale en_IN)
    ✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
      See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information.
      On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint: sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
      On Fedora: dnf install libstdc++.i686
      On Arch: pacman -S lib32-gcc-libs

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I followed the instruction provided and installed the lib32-gcc-libs package using the command `pacman -S lib32-gcc-libs`, but I am still getting the same error message. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?